# Umask via SAS code

Tags: sas

I have been trying to change the permissions of all the output datasets created by a SAS code.
I know that I can use the chmod command post a dataset's creation to change the permissions. But, what if I have multiple outputs from a code and i want to change their permissions, then how can I dynamically apply chmod on every dataset created in the code without having to manually supply dataset names?
Ex. If my SAS code does this :

```
`Data Lib1.test1
     Lib2.test2
     Lib3.test3;
Set Work.Test;
If (certain conditions) then output Lib1.test1;
If (certain conditions) then output Lib2.test2;
If (certain conditions) then output Lib3.test3;
run;`
```

How can I apply chmod to all these datasets after they have been created without having to manually supply the dataset names. I know `&syslast` can give me the last touched dataset, but what about the other two?
P.S. I can't update the Data step code block here, I can only add code post the end of the Data step mentioned above.

I tried using the Umask command in the very beginning of the session, but it does not let me set the execute permissions. 
`X  umask 000`
It only sets `rw,rw,rw` settings for datasets does not give `u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx` permissions.

Comment: Why would you want to set execute flags on a dataset?

Comment: Right, makes sense! But, is there a way to achieve this query using chmod and not Umask?

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

1. Try setting the setgid bit on the folders where your datasets are created. They should then automatically inherit their group permissions from the folder. E.g. `chmod g+s /mydir`
2. Use a wildcard command to set the permissions for all sas datasets in a folder, e.g. `chmod g=rw /mydir/*.sas7bdat`

Comment: Could you help elaborate on option 1, how can I achieve that . Say I have multiple directories being used in a code how can I set the SGID for all those directories and then have the datasets/output files be created with the group id name and permissions? How can I achieve this at run time using my SAS code?  Option 2 won't help much since I might not have rights to all datasets in those directories.

Comment: You need to make sure that permissions are set on each folder before you start using it. If you want to do this for all subfolders inside `mydir`, try something like `find /mydir -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;`. N.B. don't do this for the top-level folder `/` as this will probably break something. If you don't own the folders yourself, get an admin or the owners to do it for you.

Comment: Makes sense, I'm not the admin so will try to have the request raised. thanks! :-)